# Taylor's Expansion II

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Find the second degree Taylor polynomial for
>
> $f(x,y) = e^{xy+2x+y+2}$
>
> centered at $(x_0, y_0) = (-3, -2)$.

Hi, I'm wondering if anyone can help me with this Taylor Expansion question as I'm unsure on how to tackle it.

I know that I am supposed to get the answer of $-3-2y+2(y+2)^2+(x+3)(y+2)$

So far I have tried to take this approach:

finding $f(x,y)$ and $f(-3,-2)$:

$f(x,y)=e^{xy+2x+y+2}$

and hence $f(-3,-2)= e^0=1$

I have also found $f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y),f_{xx}(x,y),f_{yy}(x,y),f_{xy}(x,y)$ and the value of each using the boundaries given:

$f_x=0, f_y=-2, f_{xx}=0, f_{yy}=4, f_{xy}=1$

but here is where I get stuck. I know that there is a remainder theorem for the double differentiated terms but I'm not sure if this is what I should be looking at.

Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Use curly brackets. `e^{2x}` for $e^{2x}$, for example.

Comment: Ah thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only asked for the second degree Taylor polynomial, the remainder term is not necessary here.

Recall the definition:

$$P_2(x,y) = f + f_x(x+3)+f_y(y+2) + \frac {f_{xx}}2(x+3)^2+f_{xy}(x+3)(y+2)+\frac {f_{yy}}2(y+2)^2$$

where all $f$ and all its derivatives are evaluated at the center $(-3,-2)$.

Hence

$$P_2(x,y) = 1-2(y+2)+(x+3)(y+2)+2(y+2)^2$$

which is equivalent to the answer.